# Warning CS8032 An instance of analyzer Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator cannot be created

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor

Using VS2019 latest version 19.9.4 and installed .NET SDK 6.0.100-preview.3 Now I cannot compile the project anymore cause it gives the error described below. If I revert to NET 5.0 it works fine.
The reason for 6.0 is to use the Hot-Reload feature for Blazor. I am now in the phase to design several UI and it should save me a lot of time.

> Warning   CS8032  An instance of analyzer Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator cannot be created from C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100-preview.3.21202.5\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\source-generators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=3.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..   RPManager   C:\AppCenter\RPManager\CSC  1   Active

Comment: Try a clean build.  The compile dependencies do not recognize a Net Version change.  So you may have intermediate obj files that need to be rebuilt.

Comment: I have done that already. Clean, Build, Rebuild and even deleted the entire Bin\Debug folder the error still there.

Comment: Did you download the Core Preview as well? See https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0?force_isolation=true

Comment: I only downloaded and installed the SDK 6.0.100-preview 3 ->Installers-> Windows ->x64.     I didn't download or install any Binaries.

Comment: Did you have the missing file "The system cannot find the file specified"?

Comment: Nope. There is no CSC subfolder on C:\AppCenter\RPManager\CSC

Comment: Is Razor settings set to correct version of Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the new **Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview**
*Version 16.10.0 Preview 2.0* when using .Net 6 Preview 3.

Answer (score 5):

This bug has to do with some versions of SDK.

Same problem occurred when building in Visual Studio 2022 17.0.6 using SDK 6.0.200. causing 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis not to load file or assembly, and omnisharp in vscode broken on 6.0.200 with this exception.

To fix this error,either

**- Update visual studio to the latest version. or**

**- downgrade the SDK version by adding a global.json file to specify which SDK to use.**

Comment: I was using Visual Studio 2022 17.0.6 with SDK 6.0.200 and had the same problem. Upgrading VS to 17.1.13 solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was using VS 17.0.6 from the LTSC 17.0 channel. Setting it to the Current or 17.2 channel and upgrading to 17.2.1 resolved the issue.

1. From within VS, select `Help > Check for Updates`.
2. Click `Change update settings`.
3. Select the `Current` or `LTSC version 17.2` update channels.
4. Click `OK`.
5. Click `Update`.

Comment: For me worked only this procedure.
If you have installed 17.0 LTSC and update using standard procedure you will remain on 17.0 LTSC and now (end of June 2022) you will install version 17.0.11 that still has the issue. Using this procedure you will upgrade to 17.2.x that solve the problem.
Probably it could work also installing only the latest .Net Core SDK but after 4 hours spent installing Visual Studios I'm not going to try.